# Real AJAX uploader doesn't insert into my database

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I'm using Alban Xhaferllari AJAX multiple uploader and I have an issue with inserting data to my database. Here is the link to the [upload.php](https://github.com/albanx/real-ajax-uploader/blob/master/upload.php). here is my code that it doesn't work.

```
function success($file_path)
{
 $conn = new mysqli("localhost", "xxxxx", "xxxxxxxx");
 $conn->set_charset("utf8");
 $conn->select_db("xxxxxxx");
 $id = $conn->query("INSERT INTO Galerie (Poza) VALUES($file_path) ");
}
```

This is the code from their website dunno what's wrong cause I dont get any error but still it doesn't insert.

Comment: The success function is just a function called at the end of the upload process. The inside code is not part of the uploader so the error is just there

Answer (score 1):

Please correct following it works for me

```
$id = $conn->query("INSERT INTO Galerie (Poza) VALUES('$file_path') ");
```